# Python Pandas - Indexing job data per day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, indexing

I have a data frame of employees and job dates for a month. I need to index each job for every given day like so.

| employee | job_time | nth_job |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Harry | 1/11/21 9:00 | 1 |
| Harry | 1/11/21 9:30 | 2 |
| Harry | 1/11/21 10:00 | 3 |
| Harry | 2/11/21 9:00 | 1 |
| Harry | 2/11/21 9:30 | 2 |
| Ben | 1/11/21 9:00 | 1 |
| Ben | 1/11/21 9:30 | 2 |
| Ben | 1/11/21 10:00 | 3 |
| Ben | 2/11/21 9:00 | 1 |
| Ben | 2/11/21 9:30 | 2 |

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert column to datetimes, so possible use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with monthly periods:

```
#format MM/DD/YY HH:MM
df['job_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['job_time'], format='%m/%d/%y %H:%M')

#format DD/MM/YY HH:MM
#df['job_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['job_time'], format='%d/%m/%y %H:%M')

df['nth'] = df.groupby(['employee', df['job_time'].dt.to_period('m')]).cumcount().add(1)
print (df)
  employee            job_time  nth_job  nth
0    Harry 2021-01-11 09:00:00        1    1
1    Harry 2021-01-11 09:30:00        2    2
2    Harry 2021-01-11 10:00:00        3    3
3    Harry 2021-02-11 09:00:00        1    1
4    Harry 2021-02-11 09:30:00        2    2
5      Ben 2021-01-11 09:00:00        1    1
6      Ben 2021-01-11 09:30:00        2    2
7      Ben 2021-01-11 10:00:00        3    3
8      Ben 2021-02-11 09:00:00        1    1
9      Ben 2021-02-11 09:30:00        2    2
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, this worked perfectly until the 13th of the month where it switches between British and American date formatting, any idea why this occurs?

Comment: @bevloy - Is `2/11/21 9:00` date with November or with February?

Comment: @bevloy - answer is edited.

Comment: I should have clarified, I'm using British formatting. So dd/mm/yy. So that date will be 2nd November.

Comment: I used this and had this error returned. ValueError: time data '01/10/2021 11:33' does not match format '%m/%d/%y %H:%M' (match)

Comment: @bevloy - there is year in `YYYY`, so change `%y` to `%Y` by `df['job_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['job_time'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')`

Comment: @jezreal Perfect thank you! That gave me the cumulative total for the month, all that was left to do was change it to 'dt.to_period('d')' for the running daily total. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239731/discussion-between-bevloy-and-jezrael).